# Reference Client (UA.-.NETStandard-master) is BadNotConnected

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, plc, opc-ua

I have a question that I already asked on the GitHub forum. Unfortunately I didn't get an answer there and I hope that you can help me here. If I do get an answer in the GitHub forum, I'll name it here. My GitHubPost can be found under the following link:

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/1139

I will still copy the post from the GitHub forum here if the link no longer works at some point.

I downloaded the OPC UA standard project from github (https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard).
I would like to use the Reference Client there to access a Beckhoff PLC (server).
To do this, I opened the project in VS2017 and set the Reference Client as the startup project. Then I started the project with F5.
The following window opened:

[Reference_Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFE1o.png)

If I now specify the IP address and the port of my PLC (as shown above) and then click on "Connect",
the client sometimes establishes a connection to the PLC and sometimes I get the following error message:

[Error_Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njGBF.png)

In about 80% of the cases there is this error message and the client does not connect to the server.
In about 20% of the cases a connection to the server is established and I can read and write variables from the server.
I didn't change the program and it seems completely arbitrary when the connection can be established and when not.
Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1: More detailed error message**

The following screenshot shows the details of the error message. I have estimated some parts of the storage path.

[Detailed_Error_Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylu1a.png)

Comment: Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 and require TLS 1.2.1.3 to be used. In June this year Microsoft pushed a security update disabling TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers but not clients.  So first some server may have the security push and others may not.  Clients if the version of TLS is not specified uses the default.   The defaults depends on the version of windows, the version of Net that was used to compile, and the IE setting of the user where TLS version can be specified.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to determine the TLS version being used.

Comment: Can you connect with any other client, for example the Prosys OPC UA Browser or UaExpert?

Comment: @JouniAro Thanks for your answer. I can connect the PLC to a UaExpert client via OPC UA. It always works reliably. With VS2017, however, I have the problem described in the question.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your answer too. I'll check that and then let you know.

Comment: Microsoft keeps on changing defaults with each Net release.  So the default TLS version in VS2017 is different from VS2019.  VS2017 is probably using either TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.  VS2019 is using TLS 1.3.

Comment: @jdweng OPC UA TCP is not using TLS

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the .NET Standard Stack, so you will just need to wait for an answer from the guys maintaining that. Meanwhile, you can try the .NET Legacy version or an older version of the Standard Stack, in case this is a regression, if you are in a hurry.

Comment: @Jouni Aro : It may not be expletively using TLS but if the URL is HTTPS than it will use TLS.  there are a lot of combination of settings on client and server that will determine if TLS is actually being used.  Best thing is like I suggested is check with a sniffer.

Comment: @jdweng I checked the communication with Wireshark and in my case no TLS is used by OPC UA.

Comment: @JouniAro I have now tried the last three versions of the .NET Standard Stack and I get the same error message with all three. You write that I should contact the person who is maintaining that. Where exactly can I contact those who are responsible?

Comment: Are you using Core?  Do you have latest version of operating system?  the operating system should be handling the TLS and older version of operating system may not support the latest TLS.

Comment: @BeclkhoffPLC I mean you will have to wait for response to the Github issue: that's where the maintainers are.

Comment: @jdweng I repeat: OPC UA is not using TLS.

Comment: @Jouni Aro : Lets see what the OPS says.  When TLS is not specified in application it uses the default of the operating system.  So even if the OPC UA doesn't use it the operating system may use it.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the answer. I'm using .NET Core 2.1. I have updated both VS2017 and Windows 10 to the current version. Regarding TLS: I recorded the network traffic when I tried to connect to Wireshark. Do I see that correctly that the TLS protocol should then be in Wireshark in the "Protocol" column? That's not the case.

Comment: TLS if being used would be in the Protocol column.  Check status in the response.  Should be 200 OK if goo or a 400/500 Error if bad.

Comment: @jdweng When I use Wireshark, no messages with TLS are shown in the protocol column. Are there any other possible reasons for the error message? I set "none" as a security measure. Could it be that I still have to state this somewhere in the source code of the project?

Comment: Since it is intermittent you may have bad hardware.  I would do a ping with large packets and let it run for a few minutes to see if there are errors.  Try from cmd.exe >Ping -t -l 65500 IP

Comment: @jdweng I tried the ping for several minutes and the PLC always answers reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the exception details to your post, it would be helpful to see at which place the ServiceResultException is triggered.

Comment: I included a screenshot of the detailed error message in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the many answers. I have been able to narrow down the cause of the problem now. I found the tip in the Github forum that you should comment out all security mechanisms:

> You modify your code private static void CheckCertificateDomain(ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint) to return true always, and add AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates true into config of the client.
> This is just for developing and troubleshooting of course.

Source: [Github tip](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/635)

I did exactly that and then tried to connect again. I no longer receive an error message, but the operating window for OPC UA crashes. VS2017 itself does not crash, only the operating window in which the IP address can be entered and the connection can be established. When I record the network traffic with Wireshark during the crash, it can be seen that the connection (although the operating window has crashed) was successful. Data is exchanged between the client (VS2017) and the server (Beckhoff PLC).

My new approach is now to no longer use this operating window, but to write a new program. I would like to continue using the library I have used so far. The received and sent variables should then be displayed via the console.

Since this no longer has anything to do with my original question, I will make a new post for questions about this program if necessary and then add the link here.